# How to serialize XML to Action method parameters in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-2, xml-serialization

Our current web site need to integrate with partners' sites in which **XML** (with Http Post) is uesed as communication protocol.

Do you know how to map XML elements, like below, to Action method parameters?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xBalance>
    <MemberCode>bu00001</MemberCode>
</xBalance>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom model binder. Start with a view model which will represent this XML structure:

```
[XmlRoot("xBalance")]
public class XBalance
{
    public string MemberCode { get; set; }
}
```

then write a custom model binder for this view model:

```
public class XBalanceModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XBalance));
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(XBalance), new XBalanceModelBinder());
```

Now your controller action might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(XBalance model)
{
    ...
}
```

You might need to decorate your action with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute as you will be POSTing XML to it and ASP.NET doesn't like characters such as `<` and `>` to be sent to the server.